# EF Migrations - There is already an object named '' in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am having trouble adding a new table to my database. these are the commands I entered when trying to add the new migration:

```
Add-Migration AdminSett
```

> Scaffolding migration 'AdminSett'. The Designer Code for this
>   migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model.
>   This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you
>   scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your
>   model that you want to include in this migration, then you can
>   re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration AdminSett' again.

```
Update-Database AdminSett
```

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
>   to the target database. Applying explicit migrations:
>   [201607011035464_AdminSett]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201607011035464_AdminSett. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AdminSettings' in the
>   database.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) ClientConnectionId:dec63212-4546-48a9-bf8e-9e2b8548fcf3 Error
>   Number:2714,State:6,Class:16 There is already an object named
>   'AdminSettings' in the database.

Also in the _Migrations table in the database I there is no row for the migration with the name: AdminSett

Comment: Looks like you've already got an `AdminSettings` table... So, how did table `AdminSettings` get into the database already?

Comment: There is only one table in the Database called AdminSettings and its the one I just created so Im not sure why it is saying this

Comment: You created it manually? With SQL statements?

Comment: Yes I created the table, created the class and then created the DBset and then I ran the migrations and I am getting this error

Comment: But the migration is the thing that creates the table and it deduces that it should do so by looking at your data model and comparing it with data in the _migrations table, not with the actual schema of your database. If you've created the table by hand, you've now got a schema that diverges from the data in _migrations... so of course the migration will fail. Either you do all your schema modifications with migrations, or nothing. EF can't guess at what to do if you've been monkeying with the database.

Comment: *Yes I created the table* -- So, there's the error, EF should do that. I consider this question close-worthy as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question when trying to figure out why my online azure database would not accept my update command complaining about the same issue.

Upon inspecting the _EFMigrationHistory table I found that the online database was missing several entries for migrations which had already happened to the online database (not sure why this is, possibly I uploaded the datapac to the database and that didn't include the _EFMigrationHistory table?).

At any rate I solved the problem by copying all the relevant migrations from myu local to the online database so that EF knew which migration it should start running from.

Answer (score -1):

There is a table in the database with name of **Admin Setting**, you should drop it manually from the database, after that run update-database command to update the database.